# google script project Resources not shown

Tags: triggers, project

HELP!!! I was working with a lot of projects until now and everything was fine.

Suddenly now, when I try to set a new project trigger, instead of getting Under Resources => Current project's triggers, I'm getting Libraries,Cloud Platform project, Advanced Google Services

Where did the project's triggers settings go???

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find it at first either, but then noticed that there is a little clock (or timer) icon in the task bar (below the menus and to the right of the floppy disc icon).  That takes you back to where the trigger settings are.  Perhaps that timer icon has been there all along.  I don't know, but I think that's what you're looking for.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9xvs.jpg)